# Minkowski's Convex Body Thm.

Tags: number-theory

Show that any lattice  $\Lambda$ in the plane contains a nonzero point $(x,y)$ such that $$x^2+y^2\leq \dfrac{4d(\Lambda)}{\pi}$$

I know that this is a simple proof once we can figure out how to apply Minkowski.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r^2 = 4d(\Lambda)/\pi$.  Consider the circle $C_\epsilon$ of radius $r+\epsilon$ centered at (0,0), so that its area is slightly bigger than $4d(\Lambda)$.  Then by Minkowski there is a nonzero lattice point in $C_\epsilon$.  Let $\epsilon \to 0$.  For sufficiently small (but positive) $\epsilon$, there are no lattice points in the region between radii $r$ and $r+\epsilon$, so the lattice point given by Minkowski has to lie on or inside the circle of radius $r$.